# Android \ iOS camera permissions - no response from the mobile user

Tags: android, ios, cordova, camera, android-camera

In a website opened on the mobile device (can be chrome on Android and Safari on iOS) - I'm asking for the user permission to access the device's camera.

I have cases in which the user doesn't response to the permissions popup which is shown by the mobile OS

In case the mobile user doesn't response - the mobile web site is stuck - waiting for the user to response to the permissions popup

Can I define a timeout for the permissions pop-up after which the user will be redirected to another URL? Is it possible on both iOS & Android?

Comment: Is it really necessary? The user won't be looking at the permission screen for long. They will have to act. Just wondering.

Comment: You will be surprised how often it happens

Answer (score 0):

The responsibility of handling the UX in the right way falls on your shoulders as a developer.

The permission dialog in general provides 3 states

1. Block
2. Allow
3. Dismiss

and lastly not a state but user can leave the pop up there without any activity

There is no way to get around this behaviour for obvious (or not) reasons.

Displaying the pop up at the time of accessing the "page" which unfortunately provides often very little context is hardly good UX. I suggest you launch the permission pop up only after you "explained" to the user why you require the access and how your website will benefit from it.

FYI: this is not just for mobile browsers but desktop as well